When should we use Apriltags?
I am creating my own robot using ros2 jazzy and so far it works great (both in sim and real robot), now I want to add the docking feature which is available in the nav2 stack but before doing so I am wondering what are the reasons that we may want to use apriltags for docking or for another task?
Thank you.

That's a pretty broad question, so take what I say here as a starting point, but by no means limited to these applications.
I think of QR codes (apriltags, as one example) as being useful when you want to be able to detect something lazily that you have control over (a dock, or robot interaction point, etc). These codes are easy to detect computationally efficiently so if you can get away with it, often its an accelerating factor to do so rather than developing your own classical or AI based detector for an object type. I think of them as "cheater-mode" detection. Not to be confused with something bad, I think all roboticists should want to be in "cheater-mode" whenever and whereever possible.
Often times though, you don't have the ability to plaster codes about as you wish since you're operating in someone elses spaces or its against product requirements for the kind of user-experience a company wants. In that case, codes aren't necessarily possible or a good option - and instead write something based on the obstacle class or train an AI/ML model (sometimes you can get away with something simple).
So, when do I think about using them?

R&D - just testing something quick and dirty where I need to know where something is, but I'm not thinking about the machine vision part of the problem yet
Application - when working on a robot solution that is 'back of house' away from untrained people or the general public where I can control the area
Application - when detecting something is cost or difficulty prohibitive and plastering up a limited number of QR codes is not a hindrance to the client business / location


Thank you very much for your detailed answer.
